# What item is more preferable as Katarina: Hextech Gunblade or Will of the Ancients?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have been thinking about this for quite some time now. When I have my [Ionian Boots of Lucidity](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ionian_Boots_of_Lucidity) and I got ["Hextech Revolver"](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Hextech_Revolver) as well as ["Rylai's Crystal Scepter"](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Rylai%27s_Crystal_Scepter) and [Rabadon's Deathcap](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Rabadon%27s_Deathcap) what path should I take with the "Hextech Revolver" and why? Is it situational or is one choice better than the other?

Here is my thought process:

The ["Hextech Gunblade"](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Hextech_Gunblade) provides me with almost the same amount of AP with a little AD which is nice, but not that great in my AP build. The gunblade also has a short cooldown ability that adds more burst for that little extra kick when you need it.

The ["Will of the Ancients"](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Will_of_the_Ancients) gives me 10 AP more and also adds an Aura so I boost my teammates AP by 30 and give them 20% spell vamp. In addition to that this item costs 1125 gold less to build.

I can see that the Hextech Gunblade is better by itself, but is it worth the extra money you have to invest to get it?

Comment: It depends what you are leveling first, because only her bouncing blades and ultimate scale with the AD. Shunpo is pure AP.

Comment: Neither are good in kat. Building a haunting guise followed by abyssel and then a deathcap is much better. Believe me

Comment: Kat needs her first target to die in order to keep chaining spells. In most cases Gunblade is the better option solely because it enables this. It also gives Kat much needed CC to help you out if you don't already have Rylai's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should definitly get a Hextech Gunblade over Will of the Ancients(WotA). It gives you more damage (your abilities scale of Attack Damage as well) and it has an active CC spell, and Katarin lacks CC. I would definitly always build Hextech Gunblade as first item on her, and I saw many pro players (like Scarra, who is known for his Katarina) do the same, simply cause you need every single stat of the item.

You used to get WotA on Katarina in double AP team compositions, but since they nerfed it pretty hard, its not that common anymore, and I wouldn't buy WotA.

Answer (score 2):

Katarina has to snowball in order to do well in a game, for this reason rushing Will of the Ancients is a bad idea because it delays your damage too much, making it harder to snowball. This is also the reason you'll see every good Katarina player get the Gunblade over Rylais and finish it fairly late if at all.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with the answers given here, one thing to be aware of is not getting too set in a build or thinking that there is only one way to play a certain champion.  The reality is that depending on the game certain things may be better than others.  I can certainly think of a couple situations where Will of the Ancients would be better than Gunblade, but it is true that more often than not Gunblade is better.  Just be careful when asking questions like this

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it really depends how your laning if you do horribly in the lane phase and can't roam to get kills then try will of the ancients as a last resort but always go for gun blade over will of the ancients because you wasting some money on the mana regen.
If you are last hitting under turret a lot then get bilge water cutlass for the ad to help last hitting under turret, the get gun blade